# Any Java Bytecode Generation Guide?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, pascal, bytecode

we're writing some sort of **compiler** from **Pascal** to **JVM Bytecode**. And we've already implemented an expression tree generation, so the next step should be the creation of `.class` file. Can you suggest any guide/tutorial of how to generate any `.class` file at least from some static data? Because I've googled for 2 hours already and read JVM specification, but I really need some even simplest example to start developing the whole stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is an example file inside [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) folder that you download. It's called **Helloworld** and it's located in `examples` subfolder. It shows how to compile (generate from scratch) `.class` file that corresponds to simple hello world app. It also shows how to get date from `.class` files but it's another story.

Maybe this is'n the best way, but when you need to start with java byte code generation and you need some basic examples it's a good idea to have a look at [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and the examples that are bundled within standard package.

Moreover Groovy uses ASM to generate its code :)

Answer (score 6):

Someone has already written a widely-used byte code generation library: [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/).

You'd have it knocked if you could figure out how to get your AST into CGLIB.

Comment: thank you! the only sad thing is that there are no tutorials about code generation :( only about `.class` files manipulations. Anyways I'll try to come up with some solution

Comment: Would it work if you could figure out how to map your Pascal AST onto Java Beans?  That's the hard part, since Pascal doesn't support objects as far as I know.  CGLIB can't help you with that; no library will do that automagically.  That's where you and your domain knowledge come in.

Comment: Pascal doesn't support objects? It's not true for decades.

Comment: Been decades since I wrote it, so that's my mistake.   I have no idea of how object-oriented the source code is, and neither does anyone else except the OP.

Comment: avra: pascal doesn't, object Pascal (Apple, later turbo pascal and Delphi) does

Comment: @avra object pascal is crappy, it seams that it's pre-delphi state of pascal :) Moreover when working with non-OOP it's quite easy to gen java `.class`, you just make one file and put all the procedures/functions to methods, and all the app code in **main** method and all the variables as class fields :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are aware, but there is a [backend](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_JVM) for the FPC that generates bytecode compliant to the JDK 1.5. The development looks fairly recent (November 2011). You should have a look at it.

Comment: +1.  Note that it is GPL though, not an ideal source if you want to sell the result.

Comment: Thans, it's really interesting stuff. I won't sell it. It's a project made during the compilers course in the university. But as all out schools teach **pascal** maybe I'll make some **NetBeans** module, so the pupils will have some nice IDE

Comment: Why not directly use Lazarus? It is customizable, and they are working on an educational edition? http://lazarus.freepascal.org http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_for_education

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of widely-used bytecode generation projects.

ASM and CGLib are probably the two best examples.

You probably don't want to build a generation library for yourself from scratch - it's a lot of work, difficult to get right and probably doesn't offer you much over using an existing project.

ASM is widely used by non-Java languages on the JVM, has OK-ish documentation and is not too bad to get going.

I haven't used CGLib as much, but I didn't find it as easy to get started with.

As a final data point, the Java 8 team are prototyping some of the new Java features (including lambda expressions) with ASM.